# git log command showing extra commits

Tags: git, gerrit, repo

I am running into following command `git log project-1419...6d6f52c1228e70bcad026eb402d023ce3d5fd023` which shows following commits,the list shows  commit `edfcf238 tag: project-1419` which is already tagged to `project-1419` ,why  is it showing this commit?how to avoid this?

```
usernames-MacBook-Pro-2:project gnakkala$ git log project-1419...6d6f52c1228e70bcad026eb402d023ce3d5fd023 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --graph
* 6d6f52c1 (origin/Weekly_release) <change://issue/37959336> OSmilestone: 19A156 802.1X Test Cases failing due to security dialogue pop-up (STILL FAILING)
* 6b5e5efc <change://issue/46756098> tech menu shows 0 bars erroneously for current network if we don't have an IP address assigned
* e78e923a     <change://issue/46321911> APPLE80211_M_TCPKA_TIMEOUT is getting posted twice for each TCP keep-alive timeout instance
* 4bb5b8b7 <change://issue/45958314> OS Mojave clients not joining Wi-Fi after sleep
* 33a8eb85 <change://issue/46519151> CrashTracer: wps at wps: asl_init
* 68e7e73e <change://issue/46621429> [OSmilestone] 18B75/J130: tech menu locks up on first click: [CWInterface(Private) queryScanCacheWithChannels:ssidList:maxAge:maxMissCount:maxWakeCount:maxAutoJoinCount:error:]
* bfc30c11 <change://issue/46389983> [OSmilestone 19A362 + 11/30 release] projectd crashing while toggling between AWDL AirDrop and Legacy
* 78e09047 <change://issue/46472555> milestone19A366: techAgent process is leaking based on leaks testing.
* affc189a <change://issue/46431578> J90/18E151: Authentication repeatedly failing on AppletechSecure after upgrade install
* 51ef814c <change://issue/46420325> 18C45 techAgent using 800+ MB
* 6c5fd17a <change://issue/44946795> OS should call DE for ABC when projectd receives driver_availability with certain reason/subreason codes
* edfcf238 (tag: project-1419, origin/mac_wlan_12072018a) <change://issue/46389983> [OSmilestone 19A362 + 11/30 release] projectd crashing while toggling between AWDL AirDrop and Legacy
```

Comment: Is `project-1419` a local branch as well as a tag? You can make sure you're using the tag with `git log refs/tags/project-1419...6d6f52c1`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean..my ask is I do not want to see the commits with the tag project-1419,as I am trying to get a delta using this tag

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your described behavior.  What cmbuckley suggests is as good a guess as any at why your repo would behave differently.  They understood your "ask"; they're saying that if you *also* have a branch with that name, git may not be interpreting your commit specification the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
project-1419...6d6f52c1228e70bcad026eb402d023ce3d5fd023
```

*means:*

- *L* = set(*all commits reachable from whatever hash ID the string `project-1419` translates to*)
- *R* = set(*all commits reachable from `6d6f52c1228e70bcad026eb402d023ce3d5fd023`*)
- Walk the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of these two sets.  That is, enumerate (*L \ R*) ∪ (*R \ L*).

Informally, the set difference is *all commits reachable from either commit, excluding all commits reachable from both*.  If `project-1419` is a tag that resolves to commit `edfcf238`, it will definitely be in the *L* set.  If it's not in the *R* set—something not visible from what you have shown us, except by implication—then it's in the symmetric difference.

You may have intended the syntax:

```
project-1419..6d6f52c1228e70bcad026eb402d023ce3d5fd023
```

which calls for a simple set difference operation.  Note that this syntax has *two* dots, rather than three.

(Most Git commands that walk revision ranges use these two syntaxes these ways.  The `git rebase` command doesn't; it treats three-dot specially, and does not allow two-dot syntax at all.  The `git diff` command doesn't walk revision ranges in the first place and treats both syntaxes specially.)

("Syntaxes" is an odd plural.  [Arguably, it should be syntaces, but it isn't.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/plural-of-syntax)  See the other answer as well: there's a good argument here for using *syntagma* when talking about `A..B` and `A...B`.)

Comment: Oops! :-) fixed now